# Need help to schedule jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have scheduled my job in jenkins as "0 0-12/3 * * 1-3". This will run monday to wednesday from 12am to 12pm for every 3 hours.

My question is, during the above interval if any build execution is PASS, then it should skip remaining scheduled interval for that week!!!

How to do this? can anyone Help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could try working the other way: Schedule your job to run only once per week. Then add either the Naginator or Periodic Reincarnation plugin to your Jenkins server to restart a failed build.

If that should be more liberal (as in: don't always start the job on the first possible day of the week, but rather check if a week has elapsed since the last run), you could try the following:

- Install https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin to check for further conditions
- Let your job write a file at the end of a successful run
- Check through that plugin whether

  - the file does not exist: run the job
  - the file is at least one week old: run the job
  - else: skip the job

Comment: Here i dont know when my build will come, but sure it will come on any one of these days(i.e. Monday to Wednesday), so that i have configured like this. 
But once build came, it should execute only once per week.

Comment: @naveenkumar I've added another option to my answer - maybe that suits your case better?